# Flattening object of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, data-structures

I have an object "Compact" that consists of an ID and two arrays:

```
public class Compact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int[] Number { get; set; }
        public double[] Value { get; set; }

        public Compact(int id, int[] number,  double[] value)
        {
            Id = id;
            Number = number;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

A list of Compact objects can be initialized like this:

```
List<Compact> c = new List<Compact>
        {
            new Compact(1, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.05, 0.02, 0.03 }),
            new Compact(2, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.07, 0.01, 0.04 }),
            new Compact(3, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.02, 0.025, 0.05 })
        };
```

I am looking for an elegant way to flatten this object into the object "Flattened":

```
public class Flattened
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public Flattened(int id, int number, double value)
        {
            Id = id;
            Number = number;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

The result of the flattening would correspond to this:

```
List<Flattened> f = new List<Flattened>
        {
            new Flattened(1,1,0.05),
            new Flattened(1,2,0.02),
            new Flattened(1,3,0.03),
            new Flattened(2,1,0.07),
            new Flattened(2,2,0.01),
            new Flattened(2,3,0.04),
            new Flattened(3,1,0.02),
            new Flattened(3,2,0.025),
            new Flattened(3,3,0.05)
        };
```

I am able to do the flattening using loops, but I am wondering whether there are more suited methods in terms of performance, like a Linq operation or a different collection-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run simply `for` loops.

```
List<Compact> ls = new List<Compact>
{
    new Compact(1, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.05, 0.02, 0.03 }),
    new Compact(2, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.07, 0.01, 0.04 }),
    new Compact(3, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.02, 0.025, 0.05 })
};
List<Flattened> ls2 = new List<Flattened>();
foreach (Compact compact in ls)
{
    for (var index = 0; index < compact.Number.Length; index++)
    {
        ls2.Add(new Flattened(compact.Id, compact.Number[index], compact.Value[index]));
    }
}
```

**Note** I have assumed that both arrays will have same number of items.

Comment: Hi Vivek, thank your suggestion. This is also what I would end up with myself, but I was hoping there would be some kind of cool Linq one-liner :) do you think this loop will be okay performance-wise?

Comment: It’s optimised code in terms for time complexity. You should have posted in the question if you already had implemented this as solution and mention that you are looking for better solution. Cool and less lines of code is not a good solution always @MadsGeltingBech

Comment: Yep, my bad will do ! It is still useful to see how you would implement the loops, thank you.

Comment: @MadsGeltingBech you should accept the answer if it has answered your original posted question and post new question if you have some other question

Comment: Fair enough, I have posted a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ, you can do

```
c.SelectMany(
    x => x.Number.Zip(x.Value, (n, v) => new Flattened(x.Id, n, v))
).ToList()
```

[`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) does the flattening, [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__), as its name suggests, "zips" the `Number` and `Value` arrays together, and apply the function `(n, v) => new Flattened(x.Id, n, v)` to each pair, creating a `Flattened` object from each pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq for this, a combination of `SelectMany` and `Zip` should do the trick

> `(n, v) => (n, v)` creates a tuple of pairs of `Number` and `Value`

```cs
List<Compact> ls = new List<Compact>
{
    new Compact(1, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.05, 0.02, 0.03 }),
    new Compact(2, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.07, 0.01, 0.04 }),
    new Compact(3, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[] { 0.02, 0.025, 0.05 })
};

var flattened = ls
    .SelectMany(
        c => c.Number.Zip(c.Value, (n, v) => (n, v)),
        (c, nv) => new Flattened(c.Id, nv.n, nv.v)
    ).ToList();
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJJ6fe)